# Is there a way to infer generic type from a generic type in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, generics, typescript-generics

I have this function `useFormState()` that takes object `initialValues` of type `FormType` as an argument.

```
type FormType = {
    email: string;
    password: string;
    rememberMe: boolean;
}

...

const initialValues: FormType = {
    email: '',
    password: '',
    rememberMe: false,
}

const { values, touched, errors, updateField } = useFormState<FormType, keyof FormType>(initialValues);
```

Function `useFormState()` must return objects containing keys from `FormType`:

```
touched: {
    email: true,
    password: false,
    rememberMe: false
}
```

In order to be able to type the response like this I need to extract "keys" type, so I pass it as second generic type `keyof FormType`.

And this is what my question is about - **Is there any way to pass just one type `FormType` and extract keys type internally?**

My function is defined like this:

```
const useFormer = <T, K extends keyof T>(props) => {
  ...
}
```

I could completely omit passing types and let the TS to infer the types and it kinda works but

- When I add more properties using `T` TS gets confused and infers it wrong
- I want function's user to be sure what they are passing is matching the Type they have so I think I want that one generic type.

It feels like the second one can be completely inferred `K extends keyof T` but if I pass just one type argument - TS wants second one.

Is there any way to get away with just one?

Comment: Do you mean something like [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABKMAeAKgPgBQEMBci6AlIQN4CwAUIolHCBABYCmAJudbbQNoDWLAJ6IYSAYLjAiAXUIAjOHAA2LXGADcXRAF9q2xAB9E4Ni2Cj2iSjUQAnFlBC2NeoA) or more like [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=3&ssc=13&pln=3&pc=20#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABKMAeAKgGkQaUQUwA8p8wATAZ0QGt8BPOYRdRAXhvseYD4AKAQwBczAJTCA3gFgAUIkRQ4ICAAt8ZCTLlyA2rTqIYSHAF1hAIzhwANvn5gA3JsQBfGc8QAfRODL5ghtUQpWUQAJ3woEFCHNyA)? - Basically do you ever want K to not equal key T?

Comment: I am not sure what this notation means :) Looks like a function with `touched` return prop (?) and `| | undefined {   return; }` - no clue :) I presume it is some kind of type defining function's interface? I can't really understand it, sorry.
To your question - K is always key of T, though it may be missing (`Partial<Record<K, T[K]>>`).

Comment: The `| undefined` is only that it can be either the interface or `undefined`, I added that so that I wouldn't need to actually return anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function fun<T>(a: T): {
  touched: {
    [key in keyof T]?: boolean;
  }
  values: T,
  errors: any[],
  updateField: () => void
} {
  ... // Do stuff with the inputs
}
```

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABKMAeAKgPgBQEMBci6AlIQN4CwAUIolHCBABYCmAJudbbQNoDWLAJ6IYSAYLjAiAXQD8hAEZw4AGxa4wAbi6IAvjoBuuFSBYBnQugA0OlgCc7cOxcQbBPaTZqIQABza4UCwAYjAsKhyI2MSIALyYiAZwMGzUuoiU3hAIZlB0nN684iJiQpIy8ohKqupaOumxGbra3nYsUCB2SJncdAzM7IRQXr1GJuaEuCPc9o7OhB7TtH4BQaHhkdFxCeBsLMCi7PUt+lTUKNg9rkN2pmnEAHT0jKxsD7iaQA)

This way you do not use a generic for the keyof, but rather have it computed in the function return type interface.

Comment: Oh, right, I could do that, thanks. I just had a feeling that I could assign it to `K` somehow so I won't have to repeat `key in keyof T` for each case when I need it. But it looks like there is no way to do it.

Comment: You could have either a unused default parameter that equals `keyof T`, a generic interface/type that you just reuse, or a type K = `keyof T` to achieve `K = keyof T`.